# how to install system settings

Tags: settings, system, synaptic

I installed synaptic, and it wiped out the default system settings. I didn't like synaptic so I uninstalled it, but now, I don't have system settings anymore. How can I just install the system settings package in ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: What system settings are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean System Configuration tools, I think there is a good chance if you will reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package. In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), type next command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```